# Android Studio - Run application without launcher activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, debugging, android-activity

So like everyone else, I moved to Android Studio and encountered issues.

My current issue - Android Studio won't let me run an application without a launch-able activity in the Manifest, for example, my application Pro key which isn't suppose to be launch-able and runs great with Eclipse.

Obviously it's not suppose to run but is there any way to install it directly from Studio?

Comment: Have you checked the launch configurations settings? You should be able to declare that you don't want to start an Activity.

Comment: @Niek it wouldn't let me to even select "Do not launch Activity" on the auto-generated project launch configuration but I added a new "Android Application" and now it works. You should answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Run/Debug Configurations (just next to the `launch` button in the toolbar) you can manage your application configurations. There you should be able to specify whether you want to launch an `Activity` or not.

Comment: It is strange, but with my last Android Studio when I install and launch from Android Studio, my `BrodcastReceiver` via BOOT_COMPLETED action, is reached, but via `./gradlew installDebug`, the `BroadcastReceiver` is never reached. Full question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895636/gradle-fails-vs-android-studio-for-a-headless-app-service-without-icon-launcher

Answer (score 32):

In Run/Debug Configurations in General -> Launch Options -> Launch select Nothing
like this
[image]

Answer (score 4):

For the case you mention, editing the 'Defaults' run configuration may not result in a runnable/installable app (at Android Studio 0.2.3, at least).

Instead, it is possible to run/install by defining a new run configuration:

```
Run -> Edit Configurations -> '+'
```

Select 'Do not launch Activity', but leave 'Deploy application' selected.

Answer (score 1):

**Desired Android App Module** > `LaunchOptions` > `Launch` -> **Nothing** `instead of (Activity)`